# Sharepoint as REST API Server

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, html

I am going to rewrite an application previously developed using Sharepoint 2007. I am not well versed with Sharepoint and the time allotted for the project is very limited. The client wants to keep the application's content manageable using SharePoint so rewriting it in another platform is not possible. Can I skip using controls and other SharePoint specific objects and just use plain HTML/CSS/JS? Is it possible for the SharePoint platform to act only as a REST API Server?

Comment: Do you want to access all content through REST, or just a part of it? [SharePoint 2013 REST API, endpoints, and samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj860569.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly possible. I have written 2 single page apps in SharePoint 2010 that host custom HTML/JavaScript/CSS and do not use any SharePoint controls. The HTML is hosted in the `_Layouts` folder and uses the ListData.svc and JSOM. Of course if you are going to SharePoint 2013 you have even more options available to you.

The reasons why we chose this methodology was that SharePoint already had web services, authentication/authorization, and a workflow engine so it cut down our development time in those areas. Plus the user base was already familiar with  administration of users and permissions. So it also cut down our training.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the air. While your example uses single page desigm, ours uses multipage design and the clients wants the ability to add new pages and customize the navigation menu.